# Tor browser on Yosemite logging error

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

I get this error on a Mac running OSX 10.10 ("Yosemite"):

> Firefox: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update

Tor browser  "latest Tor version". Is there anyway to remove this error? Is this a normal error? Does any body know what code might be the reason for the error?

Comment: As it stands, there is no question, and it isn't clear what you actually want! Are you trying to (1) simply notify the community about the error (as implied by the "courtesy" inclusion), in which case a Question and Answer site is probably not the correct place to do it, (2) Ask how to interpret the error message, or (3) Ask how to correct the error?

Comment: I created a [ticket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/14279) at Tor's bug tracking system. Have also a look there.